# symfony 2 validation of form over 10 length values bigint?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a value set to `bigint` in my MySQL db (bigint 20). When I set a value in the form of more than 10 characters, such as " 1234567890123 "; I get an error message stating: `This value is not valid`.

User.orm.yml

```
AppBundle\Entity\User:
type: entity
table: null
repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    fbId:
        type: bigint
        options:
             unsigned: true
    firstName:
        type: string
        length: 255
```

[View form:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax4Zz.png)

[MySql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDviZ.png)

Comment: also I tried without options: unsigned: true

Comment: Can you show us the FormType & the validator of your User entity ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably reach 32bit integer max. You can write your own validator and use PHP GMP extension: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php